# add text in canvas like paint

Tags: html, text, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to implement an html5 application that permit users to add text to my html5 cnavas.
similiar to the way we do in paint.the users will be able to modify the size of letter, type..etc

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas

Comment: @Jordan i not make myself clear.i need something like TinyMCE (http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) so when user finished the text then i adding them to the cnavas, with fillText and strokeText options

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link, this is maybe what you need: http://h4ckcod3r.in/html5app/

This was one of the first things I made in html5 canvas. You can check out the source, it is quite self-explanatory.

This is a simple paint application, & *you should be able to modify it to add text feature too.*

*The logic for that should be you should redraw the canvas each time the user changes font, font-size, type, text width etc.  I guess you know about the `fillText` and `strokeText` options.*

Comment: i only need to wrtite text, dont need to draw lines. but this is a cool app.

Comment: yeah that is much simpler, just redraw the canvas each time taking required parameters (x,y,fill/stroke, size) etc

Comment: & do check out the various text options in this page: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-font-size/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at **[html2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)** it reads a page (or elements) styles and renders them to canvas. Its not 100% perfect, but it works pretty well.

[Check out some of the examples](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) such as [this one](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/tests/text.html) (click to cycle between text, and canvas rendered) which is pretty close to what you are trying to do. This should at least get you down the right path.